# Satellite image data that allows input of a lat/lng and returns radius around coordinates

Tags: geospatial, usa, images, aerial-photography

I'm looking for a dataset of satellite image data of the USA that would allow me to enter a lat/lng center and get the satellite image of the area around the center.

I can currently use the Google Static Maps API but their licensing does not allow me to create products off their images which is a requirement. I am looking for open source satellite images that I can use to create new features for a dataset without any licensing restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

A major source for openly available Satellite Imagery is the [USGS EarthExplorer Platform](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). This contains a huge swath of remotely-sensed data at the global scale going back to the 1980s and is updated in near-real-time.

An API for this available but it seems the URL to it is broken/forbidden. Here is link to a GitHub project ([yannforget/satxplore](https://github.com/yannforget/landsatxplore)) created to provide a Python wrapper for it. I haven't tried it myself but it looks promising.

EDIT: The URL isn't broken, you just need to register! https://ers.cr.usgs.gov/register/